# R Using Sample to Create Column of Matrix with Random numbers

Tags: r, matrix

With the help of people on this site I have a matrix `y` that looks similar to this (but much more simplified).

```
1,3
1,3
1,3
7,1
8,2
8,2
```

I have created a third column that generates random numbers (without replacement for each of the repeating chunks using this code `j=cbind(y,sample(1:99999,y[,2],replace=FALSE))`.

Matrix `j` looks like this:

```
1,3,4520
1,3,7980
1,3,950
7,1,2
8,3,4520
8,3,7980
8,3,950
```

How do I obtain truly random numbers for my third column such that for each of the repeating rows i.e. 3,then 1, then 2 I get a random number that is not replicated within that repeating part (`replace = FALSE`)?

Comment: Sorry, you seem to have left a comment and deleted it. Could you write it again? I understand that the answer I've doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

**Why this happens:**

The problem is that `sample` command structure is:

```
sample(vector of values, how many?, replace = FALSE or TRUE)
```

here, "how many?" is supposed to be ONE value. Since you provide the whole of the second column of `y`, it just picks the first value which is `3` and so it reads as:

```
set.seed(45) # just for reproducibility
sample(1:99999, 3, replace = F)
```

And for this seed, the values are:

```
# [1] 63337 31754 24092
```

And since there are only 3 values are you're binding it to your matrix with 6 rows, it "recycles" the values (meaning, it repeats the values in the same order). So, you get:

```
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]    1    3 63337
# [2,]    1    3 31754
# [3,]    1    3 24092
# [4,]    7    1 63337
# [5,]    8    2 31754
# [6,]    8    2 24092
```

See that the values repeat. For the matrix you've shown, I've no idea how the `7,1,2` occurs. As the first value of your matrix in `y[,2] = 3`.

**What you should do instead:**

```
y <- cbind(y, sample(1:99999, nrow(y), replace = FALSE))
```

This asks `sample` to generate `nrow(y) = 6` (here) values without replacement. This would generate non-identical values of length 6 and that'll be binded to your matrix `y`.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you want:

```
j <- cbind(y, unlist(sapply(unique(y[,2]), function(n) sample(1:99999, n))))
```

edit: There was an error in code. Function `unique` is of course needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this. I get 6 unique values here as well. How is this different from `sample(1:99999, 6)` exactly?

Comment: With the example data provided, unique(y[,2]) is c(3,1,2). Now with sapply you first sample 3 values from 1:99999, then 1 value, and finally 2 values. There can be same values in these groups, for example if you sample from 1:10 and use set.seed(1), you get c(3, 4, 5, 10, 3, 9). I agree that the code is bit cryptic, hopefully this cleared the issue.

Comment: It seems a bit far fetched to try to get repeating values within groups with a range of 1:99999 and picking a few. But I get your point.

Comment: True, but that was part of the question, and it was said that the example data is much simplified from the actual case.

Comment: It says: `How do I obtain truly random numbers for my third column such that for each of the repeating rows I get a random number that is not replicated within that repeating part?`. I failed to read this as  sample numbers for each group.

Comment: I also failed to read it that way first, but the comment OP deleted below your answer was about this issue. No idea why it was deleted.

Comment: It is either one of all our answers. I think there's no other possibility :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't get this without a loop. Maybe someone else can get more elegant solution. For me the problem is to sample with repetition intra-group and without repetition inter-group

```
ll <- split(dat, paste(dat$V1,dat$V2,sep=''))
ll.length <- by(dat, paste(dat$V1,dat$V2,sep=''),nrow)
z <- rep(0,nrow(dat))  

SET <- seq(1,100)  ## we can change 100 by 99999 for example
v =1
for (i in seq_along(ll)){
  SET <- SET[is.na(match(z,SET))]
  nn   <- nrow(ll[[i]]) 
  z[v:(v+nn-1)] <- sample(SET,nn,rep=TRUE) 
  v <- v+nn
}

 z
[1]  35  77  94 100  23  59
```

Comment: this seems to the opposite of what Hemmo has given. His seems to be intra-group without repetition and inter-group with (possible) repetition.